# Node.js Request Module Get Intermittent 401 Resonse

Tags: node.js, request, http-status-code-401

I have the following code in a Node.js application running under IIS (IISNode):

```
app.get('/ninja/user/:id', function(req, res) {

    rq.get('https://apps.xxxxxx.xx.xxx/onb/user/' + req.params.id, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }, (error, response, body)=>{
        res.send(body);
    });

});
```

I am testing in Postman and sometimes it works, i.e., I get a JSON response, but sometimes (at least 50% of the time) I get a 401 back.

The "ninja" service is running on my PC under IIS. This service call always returns 200; it's the response from the service call to API within ninja that is intermittently returning 401.

I've tried Fiddler but because the call is on my PC there's really nothing to analyze since it's always coming back 200; I don't have access to the server where the other service is running.

I cannot understand why this issue is random.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The underlying issue hasn't been solved but the reason the error was intermittent was because of the load balancer. Although I specified a specific server in the URL, I found out from our network team that they had disabled this feature. Once they turned it back on and I was able to hit a specific server all was well.

As for the server causing the issue (401), we still don't know what's causing it.